# create-react-app taking up too much disk space and time

Tags: reactjs

It's my first experience with react and as stated in official docs, I was trying out `create-react-app` to create my first react app.

But I notice that it takes around 15-20 minutes to get finished( even though I have good internet connection) and once it was completed, I noticed the space taken by the newly created folder to be around 165-170 MB.

Isn't there any quicker way to get started with react as the above mentioned method probably installs some modules that are never going to be used.

Thank You.

Comment: What command did you use?

Comment: I used ``npx create-react-app first-app``

Comment: Did I do something wrong?

Comment: No, that is how it's currently used. I also get large amount of packages in node_modules but the whole thing takes no more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Time isn't a problem. But 165 MB, it doesn't seems a best way to set up anything for the first time. In a video lecture, I saw the faculty using just ``create-react-app first-app``. Would it make any difference?

Comment: No, that is the old way of doing it and would cause a lot of problems. You don't have to set up anything to make a react program but if you want to set up a comfortable develop environment (linter, build jsx and es11, webpack dev server with hot module reloading) then it needs to install a lot of packages and configure them for you. If you would do `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux` then it would install even more packages.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem when i first started learning react. What i did was i manually configured webpack to bundle my code. And then i created central node_modules folder in particular place. So anytime i want start a react project i just create a [symlink](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/symlink-tutorial-in-linux-how-to-create-and-remove-a-symbolic-link/) to the node_modules folder. And also if i want install a new package, i go the central folder and install it, so the package will be available in the node_modules folder and for any of my project that may need it. That way i only need to install a package once not every time i want to use it for a new project.

But recently i found a package manager called [pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm). Instead of downloading a package anytime need to install it, pnpm maintains a central cache of packages such that anytime you want to install a package, it just creates a symlink(or junction in windows) (similar to what i used to do).

**Conclusion**

In conclusion i would recommend you to just configure a bundler ([vite](https://vitejs.dev/) is cool) by yourself and use pnpm to install packages. You can read more about pnpm [on there website](https://pnpm.io/)